# How to assign a pointer value to a const char** after it is declared and passed as an argument to a function

Tags: c

Here is the program where I have to use `readdir()` to get file from the directory and after that I need to return back the filename in the `read_files()` function through `const char**` and later I need to use the filename to read it using `getfile()`- here I need to pass it as `const char*` in the argument, don't know how to do it?

I am getting this error `warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]`

```
typedef struct{
  DIR* path;
  struct dirent* readf;
} readfiles;

int read_files(readfiles *r, const char** file){
   if(readfiles->readf = readdir(readfiles->path)) != NULL){
     file = &(readfiles->readf->d_name);
   }
 return 0;
}

int getfile(readfiles *r, const char* filename){
  int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
  close(fd);
  return 0;
}

int main(){
 const char** filename;
 readfiles r;
 read_files(&r, filename);
 getfile(&r, *filename);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assigning `file` inside the function is not going to be reflected outside of it. Not speaking of this program not doing anything useful at all...

Comment: you mentioned only one error, but there are lot of other error exists ? read `man 2 open` & check how you use `open()`.

Comment: In C, when calling a function, you only copy and pass the values of arguments. So, when you want to modify `r`, you have to pass `&r`. So nothing is different for a pointer variable `x` ... you can imagine, still you need to pass an `&x` if you want to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the rest of the functions are correct and `readfiles->readf->d_name` points to the C string

```
int read_files(readfiles *r, char** file){
   if(readfiles->readf = readdir(readfiles->path)) != NULL){
     strcpy(*file, readfiles->readf->d_name);  // <-- copy 
   }
 return 0;
}
}

int main(){
 char fbuff[MAXFILENAME];
 char *filename = fbuff;
 readfiles r;
 read_files(&r, &filename);
 getfile(&r, *filename);
 return 0;
}
```